# Javascript - Input/text can't get focus (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus, frames

I'm doing a registry form, one of the validations is to check the database for existing username. To do that I open a php page in a separate hidden frame that checks the database and then calls a javascript funcion on the main frame to show an icon indicating if the user exists or not.

everything works fine, except in chrome that when the php page is open, the input/text loses focus and there's no way to get it back. I've tried calling focus on the element, using timeout as i've seen this solves similar issues in chrome, but nothing works so far...

any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not make an AJAX call instead of faffing with hidden frames?

Comment: does that solve my problem?

Comment: Yes it does :) thank you Jacob Walker